# Did Kylo Ren know where Luke was?

Tags: star-wars

Part of the Force Awakens was about the First Order trying to find the map to Luke Skywalker, but as seen in the Last Jedi, Kylo Ren was taught by Luke in a temple on the planet Luke was hiding on, so doesn't that mean in the Force Awakens Kylo Ren knows where Luke is all along?

Am I missing something here like the temple was on a different planet?

Comment: What's leading you to think that the temple where Luke trained his students was on the same planet as he was hiding? I don't recall us ever getting information as to where that training temple is--the structures on Ahch-To were an old, old temple, not a recent one.

Comment: In the video 'small details you missed in the last Jedi' released by looper i think there was a detail in there which he mentions which sort of implied that the temple like trained Ren at was on the same planet as where he stayed - guess he got his facts wrong or i mis-interpreted. Thanks for clearing this up though

Comment: @AidanH or he made up a bunch of crap to try to get views... but no. No-one on YouTube would ever stoop so low!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Luke exiled himself to [Ahch-To](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ahch-To), a planet in the [Unknown Regions](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Unknown_Regions).

Luke's temple was located on [Ossus](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ossus), not Ahch-To. A plot point in *The Force Awakens* is that no one (other than R2-D2) on either side of the war knew where Luke was.

> **Kylo Ren:** The map to Skywalker. We know you've
> found it, and now you're going to
> give it to the First Order.

> **Finn:** Apparently he's carrying a map that
> leads to Luke Skywalker, and
> everyone's after it.

> **Han:** Ever since Luke disappeared,
> people have been looking for him.

Comment: The temple planet has since been identified as Ossus: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ossus

Answer (score 3):

In the force awakens Han Solo says that after Luke's students were killed, Luke went searching for the first Jedi temple. Luke's own Jedi academy was on a different planet than his home in the last Jedi which was at the first Jedi temple.